# what is the name/designation for two-conductor insulated shielded copper wire for 24V that runs to the aquastat?

Tags: hot-water, terminology

I would like to order some wire online but don't know what it's called. Two-conductor shielded copper wire for 24V, insulated  so it could be secured with zip-ties to the HX supply and return pipes running between the boiler and the indirect water heater. It connects to the aquastat.  What's this kind of wire called?

Comment: We called it shielded 2 conductor wire ??? gauge or Shielded 2 conductor thermostat wire. The term depends a lot on where you purchase it. Be sure you pay attention to the temperature rating. If the insulation voltage rating is higher, great that is OK.

Comment: Are you in the U.S.? Can you please provide a pic with something familiar, like a penny or a pencil or a measuring tape in it for reference?

Comment: are you sure that it has to be shielded?

Comment: @jsotola:  Not at all sure, but I figured it couldn't hurt since these wires run under the stereo and speakers in the floor above; those speakers buzz now and then for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 18/2 or 16/2 shielded CMR will do

One lesser-known thing about the NEC is that type CM (communications) cables with the correct wire gauge and count can be freely used for any application that calls for a type CL2 or CL3 (low voltage control) cable.  So, I'd use a shielded two-conductor in-wall audio or security-alarm cable for this -- these are type CM(R), and many of them are of sufficient gauge to handle anything a thermostat cable can.